# Deploying Spring 4.1.6 mvc webapp in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, weblogic

I am developing a webapp(Spring MVC 4.1.6) and I want to deploy the app(war file) in weblogic and test it. I was using Tomcat before and it worked. But when I try deploying in weblogic, I get errors as below:

```
<Error> <org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet> <BEA-000000> `<Context initialization failedorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;`
```

I looked around and found that I need to add the following in my weblogic.xml, but it did not help.

```
  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>
```

I also tried to add this in weblogic.xml, this also did not help.

```
  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>

  <container-descriptor>
         <prefer-application-packages>
             <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
         </prefer-application-packages>
     </container-descriptor>
```

Is there anyway for me to force weblogic to use the Spring libraries from my webapp. I also looked in the lib folder of weblogic(wanted to delete the spring libraries) and did not find any Spring libraries, may be I am not looking at the right place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I feel so bad. The location of my weblogic.xml was not right. Once I placed the file in WEB-INF and it works now. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For the first step make a SpringMVC  Hello program.
Create a new Spring Project.
Give a name and chose a template Spring MVC Project
Spring will create everithing you need for project 
After that you configure pom.xml, web.xml, spring-context.xml
Also here are my project with a mysql hibernate and etc
http://www.mfp.co.rs/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/testHibernate.zip

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say make a new SpringMVC project, how do you want me to? I created my current project with eclipse and maven. So if I create another project, won't I run into the same issue? I will download you zip and try it later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- For weblogic.xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
        <wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-application-packages>
                <!-- Enforce Own library-->
                <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
                <wls:package-name>javax.inject</wls:package-name>
                <!-- Enforce JPA -->
                <wls:package-name>javax.persistence</wls:package-name>
            </wls:prefer-application-packages>
        </wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:context-root>/App</wls:context-root>
    </wls:weblogic-web-app>

For web.xml
<!-- For Servlet 2.5 web.xml -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">    


    <!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
    fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
    specified for component-scanning -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.config.ApplicationConfig,
            com.config.JpaConfig
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
        and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.config.WebMvcConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <!-- map all requests to the dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```